# Understanding why Puppeteer wont load a website

Tags: javascript, async-await, puppeteer

I have some simple code

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

async function getPic() {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://www.paniniamerica.net');
  await page.screenshot({path: 'panini.png'});

  await browser.close();
}

getPic();
```

I noticed that this specific website just times out. Other websites like google.com or even stackoverflow.com work fine. Is this website blocking this type of behavior?

This is the error it spits out.

```
    (node:63995) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Navigation failed because browser has disconnected!
    at CDPSession.LifecycleWatcher._eventListeners.helper.addEventListener (/Users//Desktop/test/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/LifecycleWatcher.js:46:107)
    at CDPSession.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at CDPSession._onClosed (/Users//Desktop/test/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Connection.js:215:10)
    at Connection._onMessage (/Users//Desktop/test/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Connection.js:105:17)
    at WebSocketTransport._ws.addEventListener.event (/Users//Desktop/test/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/WebSocketTransport.js:44:24)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (/Users//Desktop/test/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:120:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (/Users//Desktop/test/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:789:20)
    at Receiver.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at Receiver.dataMessage (/Users//Desktop/test/node_modules/ws/lib/receiver.js:422:14)
  -- ASYNC --
    at Frame.<anonymous> (/Users//Desktop/test/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/helper.js:111:15)
    at Page.goto (/Users//Desktop/test/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Page.js:674:49)
    at Page.<anonymous> (/Users//Desktop/test/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/helper.js:112:23)
    at getPic (/Users//Desktop/test/test.js:6:14)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:63995) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:63995) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: Have you tried directly in chrome browser with this link https://paniniamerica.net does it loads first ?

Comment: you meaning loading the page? yeah, it works. but loading with a script, it doesnt.

Comment: But now i tried in page directly it's not loading. it says "took long to respond  site cant be reached"

Comment: actually, yeah it might be down, but i can say the yesterday when the site was up i was getting the error.

Comment: @gowthamrajan i updated question with the error. the url needed to have www.

Comment: await page.goto('https://www.paniniamerica.net',{waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200715/discussion-between-gowtham-rajan-and-soldfor).

Comment: Sites not loading is usually a symptom of bot detection/prevention/blocking.